# Do the various Glyph effects stack?

Tags: the-witcher-3

For example I have 3 Greater Stribog glyphs that give 5% to stagger opponent. If I put three of them onto a sword, do I have 15% to stagger? The tooltips do not make this clear and unless I'm completely losing it, the in-game tutorial information doesn't even mention Glyphs.

Comment: no information on rune descriptions suggest that these would not stack, also some swords come with these effects already, I would expect that runes and glyphs would stack onto these as well. There may however be a cap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effects of the glyphs do stack on a piece of equipment. You can check this if you have a weapon with the same effect you are trying to apply. Let's say a chance to burn, your weapon has a 5% chance to burn on its own. You apply 3 glyphs that each give an additional 5%, you will now have 20% chance to burn on your weapon when you read the description. You will only see the effects stack if the weapon has that ability on it already, sadly when inspecting the weapon or armor does not show the ability in the general description unless it was pre-existing. I have done this many times with various weapons now. I might be able to get a screen shot of before and after if you doubt it, though this will take me some time.